# is that possible sending http request from lumen using guzzlehttp?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, guzzle

actually i want to validate given token .. the validate code written in another lumen package. i have got some issues when i send request to validate token. i dont know why it's not working. cant use another api inside lumen ?

if i use that check token api in postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSpJt.png. it works fine. it's thrown error when i call that api inside other lumen package

this is what i got when use this api in postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfFzk.png

error log  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds0oR.png

````
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Helpers\ResponseBuilder;

class check_customer_token_verification 
{
    public static function check($token, $vendor_id) 
    { 
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $result = $client->post('dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'token' => isset($token)?$token:'',
                    'vendor_id' => $vendor_id,
                ]
            ]); 

        $res_data = json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents()); dd($res_data);
            if ($res_data->http_code == 401) {
                return ResponseBuilder::responseResult(400, $res_data->message);
            }
        return $res_data;
    }
} ```

dump this api in postman. i got issue which is below


^ {#120
  +"http_code": 400
  +"message": """
    Server error: `POST dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
            <style>
            (truncated...)
    """
}```
````

Comment: Well I see dd($res_data); in your code.

Comment: i just die dump to know what response i get in post man..this is what i got when i dump this
 ^ {#120
  +"http_code": 400
  +"message": """
    Server error: `POST dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
            <style>
            (truncated...)
    """
}```

Comment: You need to define your form_params

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your form_params, though your code can work but I would also suggest using try catch blocks and adding your 401 exception in catch block (& other 400 in there), see the changes I have made

```
 public static function check($token, $vendor_id) 
    { 
        try{
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            define("form_params", \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::FORM_PARAMS );
            $guzzleResponse = $client->post('dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'token' => isset($token) && !empty($token) ? $token : '',
                    'vendor_id' => $vendor_id,
                ]
            ]); 
            if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
               $result = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody(),true);
               // dd($result);
            }
            
            return $result;
        }catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
           // Catch all 4XX errors 
           dd($e->getMessage, $e->getTraceAsString());
           // To catch exactly error 401 use 
           if ($e->hasResponse()){
               if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '401') {
                   return ResponseBuilder::responseResult(400, $e->getMessage());
            }
         } 
        }catch(Exception $e){
           //other errors 
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply bro.. i used this one still having same issue.. is that possible sending http request from lumen using guzzlehttp ?

Comment: yes it is possible to call one project made in lumen from another project api, by form_params you basically want headers to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, on which side you are getting 500 internal server error

Comment: i send request from pims(lumen) to crm(lumen) to validate token. from pims side i got server error exception

Comment: what do you observe in preview portion of your postman, can you edit the question to show screenshot of the error from postman

Comment: this is the dd() of $result, if yes comment it and as it is 400(or even in case of 500) it will go inside the catch block of RequestException, so add a `Log::info()` & put inside either `$e->getMessage()` or `$e->getTraceAsString()`, in it it will show complete error in your log file(for me it is `storage/logs/lumen.logs`) , also add class `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log`

Comment: lumen is trying to show the error inside html code but it is truncated so you can't view it, so using `$e->getTraceAsString()` is the best, for shortcut you can directly dd() the $e->getTraceAsString() in your RequestException catch statement

Comment: the picture you sent of error, shows that this api `dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token` has 500 error and it is trying to show the error in form of html page but the html is not complete (truncated) so request is doing its work properly but the `dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token` has errors, in order to see that error see the update answer

Comment: But when i check dev.adiswar-crm.local/custoner/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token api in postman. Its working fine. Its only throw error when i use this api inside pims (lumen)

Comment: for that you need to look at what is causing 500 error, for that try to using Exception Handling and send your error message to logs, try to find your log file, https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors

Comment: the method I have written it works I have also used it to call an api build in 1 lumen app to another. the problem is 500 server error it is coming from the api you are calling from 1st api it is trying to show error in html, but the html is truncated, so in order to see it try to use logs

Comment: i added my check token method in my question.. u can look at that. verify everthing is ok or not bro.. any changes let me know bro

Comment: can you add the log for the one from which it is called(because the log you added also is showing the truncated message) (POST dev.adiswar-crm.local/customer/crm/v-1-0-0/check-token), you are saying it is separate so it has separate logs as well.